# VSCode not executing code after receiving information from user

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

The application does not work after receiving information from the user
(odd or even finder app)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Dart scripts are run via the Debug Console where the input box works as a REPL. If you need to read input from the user, you need to change it to run in a terminal.

You can do this by creating a `launch.json` file and adfing `"console": "terminal",` as described here:

https://dartcode.org/docs/running-in-terminal/

Or you can add the [`"dart.cliConsole": "terminal"`](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartcliconsole) setting in your VS Code Workspace Settings for this project.